# Scrollview in Jfeinstein's Sliding Menu scrolls too much

Tags: android, scrollview, slidingmenu, slidingdrawer

I implemented a scrollview in my sliding menus layout and it works perfectly except for one thing. It scrolls way too much. I just want it to scroll all the way down to the button "Athletics" how could I go about doing that? Here is my layout file.

And here's a picture of what it's doing.[image: Scrolling too much]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/drawer_background"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </FrameLayout>



        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bhs_name"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5sp"
            android:src="@drawable/bhs_name" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tiger_logo_small"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/tiger_logo_small" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/random_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5sp"
            android:text="Random Text"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/go_to_website"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/admob_button_layout"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Bentonville Website"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/go_to_grades"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/admob_button_layout"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5sp"
            android:text="Grades"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/go_to_lunch_menu"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/admob_button_layout"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5sp"
            android:text="Lunch Menu"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/go_to_bell_schedule"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/admob_button_layout"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5sp"
            android:text="Bell Schedule"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/go_to_calendar"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/admob_button_layout"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5sp"
            android:text="Calendar"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/go_to_announcements"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/admob_button_layout"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5sp"
            android:text="Announcements"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/go_to_athletics"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/admob_button_layout"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5sp"
            android:text="Athletics"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </ListView>


</LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: have you tried using android:layout_height="match_parent" for the scrollview?

Comment: @panini Yes, I've even put the Linear Layout and scroll view at 5sp but it's still the same

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, it was the drawable background I was using for the sliding menu. It was so long that it made the whole scroll view long. Took it out and it worked. Thanks though guys.